# How to set text representation of a custom object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form component and an input control in it.
Input control is attached to formGroup.
Consider this object: `{Id: 1, Text: "some text here..."}`. Like a `select or dropdown` I want to show the `Text` part in the input but send `Id` part when the form submit.

here is a proto of what the code is like:

Component.ts:

```
    Form = new FormGroup({Organ: new FormControl()});
```

component.html:

```
    <input formControlName="Organ" type="text" [readOnly]="true">
```

I also searched some keywords but irrelevent result gained.

------------------- edited --------------------------
Sorry for ambiguous question.
I know how a `select` works. But i want a simple read-only input textbox to be programmatically attach to it with value of `{Id: 1, Text: "some text here..."}` and show corresponding text in it, but internally saves Id to it's `formControl`.
for instance consider a `datepicker` which has a text representation of "1980-02-03" but when you log the form value: `console.log(this.form.value)` it shows `data` object of that represented text.
a gain! I don't want to create a datepicker or a selector. **I want to know how to set text representation of a custom object** so i changed the question topic.

Comment: It would be nice to know why -1? of course i omit some parts for simplicity, But i know principles of angular, making question and ...

Comment: Can you show your `select` or `dropdown` code in your `template` file where you want to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If your set of valid inputs is finite and can be represented as an array of `{Id: number, Text: string}` then you must use a select. Inputs are for free text which can be validated using some function but the form value will always be the entered text in the input. If you want some magic, you can always create your own custom control.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's what you want:

Component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  options = [{id: 1, text: 'text1'}, {id: 2, text: 'text2'}];
  form = new FormGroup({Organ: new FormControl()});

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <select formControlName="Organ">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">{{option.text}}</option>
  </select>
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

So you're binding `id` property to form control value, while displaying `text` property.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iuljdu